# Combining result of inner join with left join

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT name,trans FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_sids d WHERE apt='KBOS' AND name != trans  
LEFT JOIN  
(SELECT distinct c.sid_ident as name,c.fix_ident from corept.std_sid_leg as c  
   INNER JOIN  
        (SELECT sid_ident,transition_ident,max(sequence_num) seq,route_type  
         FROM corept.std_sid_leg  
         WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='KBOS'  
         GROUP BY sid_ident,transition_ident)b  
         ON c.sequence_num=b.seq and c.sid_ident=b.sid_ident and        c.transition_ident=b.transition_ident  
         WHERE c.data_supplier='J' and c.airport_ident='KBOS')right_tbl  
ON d.name=right_tbl.sid_ident;
```

This is my code..when executing i am getting error at left join saying that the syntax is wrong.Anybody help please...I have gone thru the syntax tutorials but end up with empty handed.Thank you.

Comment: This is my errror...  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN
(SELECT distinct c.sid_ident as name,c.fix_ident from corept.std_sid_' at line 2

Comment: and why don't you use union?

Comment: I need find the data differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `WHERE` clause to the end of the query. Also, what is that column `trans` in the `WHERE` clause? Where did it come from? If it is a string literal then, put it in quotes.

It should be written this way:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  trans 
FROM skyplan_deploy.deploy_sids d 
LEFT JOIN
(
   SELECT distinct c.sid_ident as name, c.fix_ident 
   from corept.std_sid_leg as c
   INNER JOIN
   (
      SELECT sid_ident, transition_ident, max(sequence_num) seq, route_type
      FROM corept.std_sid_leg
      WHERE data_supplier='J' AND airport_ident='KBOS'
      GROUP BY sid_ident,transition_ident
   ) b ON c.sequence_num=b.seq 
       and c.sid_ident = b.sid_ident 
       and c.transition_ident = b.transition_ident
    WHERE c.data_supplier='J' and c.airport_ident='KBOS'
) AS right_tbl  ON d.name = right_tbl.sid_ident
WHERE apt = 'KBOS'
  AND right_tbl.sid_ident IS NULL ;
```

Comment: +1 for sharp eyes. **`name`** if varchar should be in `quoted`.
i think it could also produce error.

Comment: @Luv Thanks - I'm not sure, I just copied it from the question, and I think the problem is the `name != trans'`, the `trans` should be quoted.

Comment: But using this i am not getting the differences in the result sets.Left join is generally used to get the rows that are present in left table but not the right.Isnt it?

Comment: @user2037445 - OK, sorry. See my edit, remove that condition and use `AND right_tbl.sid_ident IS NULL` instead, to get those rows that are in left and not in the right.